# Wordpress Query by Custom Field with date type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date, custom-fields

I want to create a query where all posts should be displayed where the custom field "expiration_date' is larger than the date from today.
Short form: if the expiration date of the post is reached, it should no longer displayed in the query

I tried with this snippet:

```
        <?php
            $today = date("Y-m-d");
            $args= array(
                'tag' => 'Pinnwand',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'key' => 'expiration_date',
                    'type' => 'DATE',
                    'value' => $today,
                    'compare' => '>'            
                )
            );
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

the expiration date is in the format (2014-10-04) for example.
But I tried also the format "Ymd" on both sides, change the compare type, or set the type as "NUMERIC" and nothing helps. The result is, that the post will always be displayed.

It would be great if somebody could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the mistake!
The correct query needs one more array(). I don't know exactly why, but in other cases the query couldn't work with it. So here is the code

```
        $args= array(
             'tag' => 'Pinnwand',
            'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'expiration',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>'            
            ),
            ),         
        );          
$my_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

Comment: The extra `array()` is needed for concatenating several meta-conditions with `AND`/`OR`. Check https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query

Answer (score 0):

You could do a two-query exclusion. First query finds all the posts you want to exclude, then loop through those and store the post IDs in an array, then call second query excluding them using 'post__not_in' with the ID array as the argument.

I would use the $wpdb object for this because it's very efficient.

For reference material: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query and
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

This chunk of code *SHOULD* do what you're trying to do or get you close to it, and I kept your tag part of the query in there too.

```
// first query to find exclusions
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$exclusions = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE expiration_date < ".$today);
if ( $exclusions ) {
foreach ( $exclusions as $exclusion ) {
    $excludeIDs[] = $exclusion->ID;
}
}

// second query using exclusion array
$args= array(
    'tag' => 'Pinnwand',
    'post__not_in' => $excludeIDs,           
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: First, thank you for the fast answer!
But sadly, it doesn't work :/
I tested it also on a different server, to prevent that it could be mistake on the server or the database

Comment: The code I pulled was pretty directly from the resource pages I provided links to in the wordpress codex. If these aren't working, I would add a print_r($exclusions); at line 5 and a print_r($my_query) after the last line, to see what the queries are returning. If they return nothing, they are broken.

Could also be that your wordpress installation is damaged or database is set up incorrectly, because your original code with the meta compare query should've worked.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I tried both things. $exclusion seems empty, the $my_query gives a lot of stuff, but it seems also there are no exclusions in. I tried the code snippet also on a complete new wordpress installation with a fresh new database. There is sadly the same result :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simpler, as stated on http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters:

```
$args= array(
    'tag' => 'Pinnwand',
    'meta_key' => 'expiration',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE',
    'meta_value' => $today,
    'meta_compare' => '>'               
);
```